# How do I run a bunch of threads in x amount of time when they all have a thread.sleep?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Full instructions: https://pasteboard.co/J2OX03H.png

Running `Thread.Sleep` on each thread seems to be preventing the Timer's `ElapsedEventHandler` from recalling `Timer_Elapsed` (FixedThreads) every x time causing it to print the threads way too fast. My goal is to have ScheduleThreads launch FixedThreads (prints threads info) every 15 seconds even if some of the threads don't finish executing/sleeping on time.

```
using FT = FixedThreads.FixedThreads;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace ScheduledThreads
{
  class ScheduledThreads
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var timer = new Timer(15000);
      timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
      timer.Enabled = true;

      while (timer.Enabled)
      {        
        var info = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (info.KeyChar == 'e')
        {
          timer.Enabled = false;
        }
      }
    }

    static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      FT.Main(null);
    }
  }
}
```

I call FixedThreads in ScheduledThreads

```
  public class FixedThreads
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Random random = new Random();
      ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);

      for (int task = 0; task < 1000; task++)
      {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Execute), task);
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(5, 801)); //this prevents schedule to work if there's more than 10-15 threads/tasks
      }
    }

    static void Execute(object callback)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
      Thread.CurrentThread.Name = callback.ToString();
      Console.WriteLine($"Thread Name: {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}");
      Console.WriteLine($"Daemon/Background Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do in the original post; it seems oddly complicated for a minimal test but but otherwise has no purpose.

Comment: @Charlie I created FixedThreads to run multiple threads while displaying their info and ScheduleThreads to launch those threads every x amount of time.

Comment: Unless this is an assignment of some kind, I'm 95% sure you are doing this the wrong way. You should not be working with low-level threads unless you really know what you are doing. Work with `Task` objects and `async` instead. Also, I doubt you actually need that many threads. If you're just trying to run stuff in the background, you probably should have only 1-2 threads and a queue or `BlockingCollection` containing the the things you want to have happen.

Comment: @mjwills It's completely ignoring Thread.Sleep inside the Execute function.

Comment: No it isn't (if you put `Thread.Sleep(random.Next(5, 801));` at the _start_ of the `Execute` method). There are 1000 threads all delaying for random amounts. Some of them for 8 milliseconds (i.e. virtually instantly). Some for 800ms (i.e. fast, but not instant). Writing to the console is relatively slow, so it looks to you like there is no delay. But there _is_ a delay. It just turns out that your 1000 threads are all delaying in a pattern such that it _looks_ like there is no delay. Your brain can't really distinguish no delay from 8ms. They look the same.

Comment: @mjwills I changed it to just 8000ms and it's still going fast. When I have Thread.Sleep after QueueUserWorkItem I notice the delay. It doesn't have any effect in the Execute function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing any output at all from the console? If not you might be deadlocked waiting for the Console.ReadKey to finish before the threads can write to the console output stream. This is because Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadKey both obtain a lock to the same object.

The Console.WriteLine only obtains the lock the first time it outputs to the stream, so an easy way to test that is to add a Console.WriteLine before you do a ReadKey.

Comment: The outputs work fine. It's the frequency of the outputs that's the problem. Thread.sleep seems to prevent the timer from recalling the function in time.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably running into the maximum thread count of the default thread pool. It's the default thread pool that handles the `Timer`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool

`Thread.Sleep` will block the thread and is usually a lazy way to get what you're really after. There are better scheduling methods that won't block or be as heavy-weight as a Thread.